# How Can I Resolve An 'npm Warn' When Using 'create-react-app'?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, warnings, create-react-app

I'm getting the following warning when using 'create-react-app': npm WARN prefer global marked@0.3.6 should be installed with -g

How can I get rid of this warning?

I looked at "Question that may already have your answer" and didn't seem to find a precise answer. However, I'm new and may have overlooked the obvious.

My installs are:

```
$ npm -v
4.3.0

$ node --version
v7.0.0

$ npm list -g create-react-app
/usr/local/lib
└── create-react-app@1.2.1

$ npm list -g marked@
/usr/local/lib
└── marked@0.3.6
```

It looks to me that this package is already installed globally.

I ran the following:

```
$ sudo npm update -g create-react-app
```

which resulted in the following:

```
$ npm list -g create-react-app
/usr/local/lib
└── create-react-app@1.3.0
```

However, I still get:

```
npm WARN prefer global marked@0.3.6 should be installed with -g
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that package includes the CLI.

Try to remove and install `create-react-app` to the newest version 1.3.0

`npm install -g create-react-app`